# How to use field variable of the model related with ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to create an `Album` model and a `Song` model which are both having a `genre` field. I want `Song` model's `genre` field is same with the `Album` model's by default.

```
class Album(models.Model):
    genre = models.TextField()

class Song(models.Model):`
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    genre = models.TextField() #The field I want to be same with its related model
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `save()` method and add the default genre before saving:

```
class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    genre = models.TextField() 

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.genre:
            self.genre = self.album.genre

        super(Song, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set it to `null`, in case it is `None`, we return the `genre` of its `Album`:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    genre = models.TextField()


class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    _genre = models.TextField(null=True, default=None)

    @property
    def genre(self):
        if self._genre is not None:
            return self._genre
        return self.album.genre

    @genre.setter
    def genre(self, value):
        self._genre = value
```

This also makes it easy when you later change the `genre` of the `Album`, in that case the songs that did not specify a genre, will thus return the "new" `genre`.